# Java Jersey - hold posted JSON values in variables

Tags: json, jpa, jersey

I have a class with date field so I can set and get the date. 
Thanks to JPA I can easily get all class rows from database ordering by whatever field in this class I'd like to.

The problem is when I'd like to get only these rows where the date is greater or lower than sent value.

something like:
`SELECT * FROM example WHERE example.date < biggerDate AND example.date > lowerDate;"`

I have in my rest a function:

```
public List<example> getDataBetween(String older, String newer) {
    return em.createQuery("SELECT row FROM example row WHERE row.date < " + older + " and > " + newer).getResultList();
}
```

So now I want to send JSON which contains older and newer values.

`{ older: '2011-01-01', newer: '2005-01-01' }`

How could I get these values in

```
@POST
@Path("/getBetween")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<example> getBetween(***WHAT SHOULD BE HERE?***) {
    //I NEED older and newer here
    return service.getDataBetween(older, newer);
}
```

I can't set Example example as getBetween parameter because Example class has no fields like older and newer. I want these parameters only for function getDataBetween call.

How could I hold a JSON in that case?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use JSONObject.

```
@POST
@Path("/getBetween")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<data> getBetween(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
    String older = json.get("older").toString();
    String newer = json.get("newer").toString();
    return ds.getDataBetween(older, newer);
}
```